# Git pull already up-to-date

Tags: git

I'm totally new to git so I'm probably making some simple newbie mistake here.

I have a server where I've cloned a remote project (but that shouldn't matter).

Then I have cloned the server-repo on my local machine. I'm making changes and adding files locally. I commit them and push the changes.

Then I want to get those changes in the working dir on the server so I do "git pull" which says:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

And no files are updated. But if I run "git status" on the server I can see the changes but in reverse, it says I have deleted the file that I added on the local machine. So it seems like git thinks that the files in the working dir on the server are the ones most up-to-date.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then I want to get those changes in the working dir on the server so I do "git pull" which says

You have to push your local changes **to** the remote server, not pull them **from** it.

In other words you're getting this the other way around: the flow is from the local to remote. You never do anything from the remote repo, unless you have a remote working copy, but that's again a *local* repo on the server.

From your local repo just use `git push` to synchronize the local changes with the remote.

Comment: Yeah i've commited and pushed them from my local machine. And then i do "git pull" on the server.

Comment: there's nothing like `git pull` from the server, if by "server" you mean the bare repo. If you want a working copy on the server you have to create another local repo on the remote machine and use it like any other local repo.

Comment: Okay, yeah i see now that git pull does nothing. But what is the point of the working dir on the server if it's impossible to have it up to date?

Comment: You miss some basic concepts. You have a bare repo which is the one you pull from and you push to. Such repo, by definition, does not have a working copy. You then clone this repo, creating as local repos with working copies (that is, because you *work* on local repos). It appears that what you want is to have two local repos, one of the which on the same machine where the bare repo is hosted. You can achieve that by cloning the repo locally, something like `git clone /local/path/on/the/remote/machine`

Comment: I'm not sure of the terminology here but what i have on the server is what i get when i clone a repo. It's a directory full of code-files (what i refer to as the working directory) and inside the working directory there is also the magical .git directory.

Comment: Ok, so what are you pushing to?

Comment: I push to that directory. If the dir on the server is /path/project1/ and /path/project1/.git the remote origin url on my local machine is user@server:/path/project1

Comment: You should have three repos: the bare repo, the local repo on your machine and the local repo on the server. How did you create the bare repo at first?

Comment: Okay, I have clearly misunderstood the concept a bit here. I didn't think there was any such thing as a "bare repo". I thought all repos where created equally and that any repo could be used as the remote origin repo for other people. The three-repos solution will work. Thanks!

Comment: Life isn't fair, not every repo is created equally. Happy versioning and consider accepting the answer.